# Referencing common binary in multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a third party DLL which I need to reference in multiple c# projects in a solution.

It is presently referenced as follows.

```
 <Reference Include="Contoso.App, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\ThirdParty\Contoso\4.0.5.0\Contoso.App.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

I have around 40 projects in my solution which reference the Contoso.App.Dll

Whenever the DLL version changes a new folder is created as follows

```
..\ThirdParty\Contoso\5.0\
```

I have to go and update all my 40 projects as follows.

```
 <Reference Include="Contoso.App, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>..\ThirdParty\Contoso\5.0\Contoso.App.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

Is there a better way to manage the version change of the DLL?

Can I create single variable in the solution and reuse it across all the projects?

Comment: Are you using it in all of the projects in your solution or is it only a subset?

Comment: Actually not all the projects. I have around 70 projects in the solutions. 40 of them reference the DLL.

Comment: Why don't you use `\ThirdParty\Contoso\CurrentVersion\Contoso.App.dll` as path and copy dll version 5.0 to it.

Comment: cant you use a nuget package ?

Comment: @TriV Your solution will not work as I also have to update version in the Reference node. See my latest Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private NuGet repository is prefect, but requires too many changes. A simpler way is to create a common project and let other projects reference this common project.

1. common.props. It's better to use solution relative path instead of `..`.

   ```
   <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <ItemGroup>
       <Reference Include="Contoso.App, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
         <HintPath>..\ThirdParty\Contoso\5.0\Contoso.App.dll</HintPath>
       </Reference>
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
2. Import it in other project.

   ```
   <Import Project="<MySolutionPath>\common.props"/>
   ```

There may be build errors in VS after changes are made in common.props because the reference is updated instantly. Verify it via command line msbuild.exe first.

Answer (score 0):

[Setup a Private Nuget Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277515/where-to-store-external-dll-files) that the rest of your team can access. 
See [Scott's](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx) answer.

**tl;dr**

- Open Visual Studios
- Create a new Empty Web Project
- Add the Nuget.Server Package

  - Package manager console: install-package nuget.server
  - Overwrite web.config: Yes
- Open Web.config
- Set appSettings

  - packagesPath: where the nuget is going to sit
- Init:

  nuget init c:\source c:\localnuget
- Push:

  nuget push {package file} -s http://localhost:51217/nuget {apikey}

[Alternate hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add flexibility to TriV's comment, you can define an environment variable (e.g. CONTOSO_VERSION) and use it in the pre-build event command to copy the DLL into your bin folder (or wherever you're referencing from) using $CONTOSO_VERSION. This way you can change the referenced DLL version back and forth via env variable. Make sure it's pre-build event for a project others depend on (or create a dummy project with others depending on it for a solution-wide pre-build event).